# cannot find remote repository in git extensions 2.48.04

Tags: git, github, repository, git-remote, git-extensions

I downloaded git Extension 2.48.04 and tried to add remote repository as GitExtensions 2.48 official documentation

http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote_feature.html

but the problem is there is no remote tab or manage remote repositories as shown in the above link

[image]

So how can I add remote repository ? (I use puTTY method)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your using windows. I would suggest downloading this version of GitHub extensions if you wish to edit a repository locally on your computer before pushing it out onto your repository. It just only requires a one time setup to connect to your github account.In addition, it provide a simple one click button that checks and syncs your remote repo to your local computer and helps push new commits. Also, you would be able to track your line by line commits as iff you were on the webpage. I hope this answer helps and the download link is noted below:
https://windows.github.com/

Comment: Yes I am windows user. I installed that but how to clone from url ?

Comment: when Click the Plus sign (Left upper corner) it ask for local path..not url

Comment: Well sorry, you can git clone directly from the github webpage. I only tried to answer in your best interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the menu because you don't have opened a git repository. 
You should either create a local repository, either browse an existing one or clone one (one of the common action displayed in the upper left) before being able to see the menu and add a remote.

That's quite logic to be able to do nothing if you have not an open repository.

@MisterSoandSo GitExtensions is a very good and efficient git client (quite better than Github client in some aspects) , so please answer the question and refrain to ask for changing the tool because you like it most...